# Most probable radius of hydrogen in its ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, hydrogen

I'm having trouble understanding how we do this. I know we must find the probability density function and then we can optimise it to find the most probable radius. I thought we would just take the square of the function and the differentiate.

I looked around and found out that we must actually multiply by $4\pi r^2$. I don't understand why even after reading [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107289/). Also, [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydr.html) site mentions that we have to multiply the square of the wave function by a spherical shell element? Can I get an intuitive perhaps geometrical reason why?

Comment: As you point out. the quantity $|\psi(r)|^2$ is the probability *density*, or the probability per unit volume. To find the probability of a particle being found between $r$ and $r + dr$ you have to multiply this be the volume element $4\pi r^2 dr$, which is the volume of the shell between the two radii $r$ and $r + dr$. You can think of this as the surface area of the shell, $4 \pi r^2$, multiplied by the width of the shell, $dr$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking (and I should not have to click on links to understand it!) - what *exactly* about *what* computation confuses you?

Comment: If you differentiate the probability density $f(r)=4\pi r^2|\psi(r)|^2$, it gives you the point where there is the maximum of the probability density, not the mean (or most probable) radius.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski So it is meaningless to speak about msot probable radius? Would make sense $dP$=$f(r)dr$ so because probability density is greater for Bohr radius that means that this is the most probable radius?

Comment: Just give the definition of the "most probable radius" and calculate it. Apart from the maximum of $f(r)$, there are the mean value $\langle r\rangle$, some dispersion around it, etc. , etc.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable radius is found by maximising *probability per unit radius*, whereas $|\psi^2|$ gives us *probability per unit volume*. To find the conversion factor from one to the other, we need to ask *how much volume is there per unit radius near a radius $r$?* The answer to this is $4 \pi r^2$.

Comment: In other words, the probability of finding the electron between distance $r$  and $r + dr$ is the probability of finding it _anywhere_ in the spherical shell that is a distance $r$ away from the nucleus. And the volume of that spherical shell is $4\pi r^2 dr$.